# Outputting Database information as XML

Tags: php, xml

I've tried about 4 different attempts to pull my database information and display it as an XML. However, when I click the designated button, it displays the error:

```
error on line 2 at column 1: Document is empty
```

My connection works fine so it's not an issue there, but I haven't tried this before so I must be overlooking something.

**Generatexml.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
include 'connection.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli_conn, $query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 
//Top of xml file
$_xml .="<people>"; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $_xml .="<person>"; 
        $_xml .="<firstname>".$row['FirstName']."</firstname>"; 
        $_xml .="<lastname>".$row['LastName']."</lastname>"; 
        $_xml .="<username>".$row['Username']."</username>"; 
        $_xml .="<password>".$row['Password']."</password>";
        $_xml .="<id>".$row['P_Id']."</id>";  
        $_xml .="</person>"; 
        } 
        $_xml .="</people>"; 
//Parse and create an xml object using the string
$xmlobj=new SimpleXMLElement($_xml);
//write to an XML file
$xmlobj->asXML('people.xml');
echo $xmlobj->asXML();
?>
```

EDIT: I have used another method, I am able to pull the database information and display it, but it's not displaying in XML format.

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

//query the database    
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users";

//run query
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sqlQuery)) {
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
echo '<results>';
echo '<people>';
    //fetch associative array 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<person>';
echo '<firstname>' . $row["FirstName"] . '</firstname>';
echo '<lastname>' . $row["LastName"] . '</lastname>';
echo '</person>';
}
echo '</people>';
}
//close the database connection
$db->close();
echo '</results>';
?>
```

Comment: Why are you generating your XML by mashing strings together and then using an XML library to convert the strings to a DOM and then immediately back to text?

Comment: I've just followed guides, yet not having much luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing to a file.

You aren't sending the content of that file to the browser.

```
echo $xmlonj->asXML();
```

Comment: Still the same error. It's stating there's a problem with the header on line 2

Comment: Are you sure that is a PHP error message about line 2 of the PHP source code and not a browser error message about line 2 of the generated XML? Probably your string mashing is producing invalid XML (I can't tell, you haven't provided the value of `$_xml`).

Comment: Sorry I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The page gives the error This page contains the following errors: --- error on line 2 at column 1: Document is empty --- Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error. --- Then the rendering is blank.

Comment: That's the second case. Your XML document is invalid. Line 2 of the PHP is fine. Something is wrong with the XML you are generating by mashing together strings. Look at the value of `$_xml`. Pass that value though something like xmllint.

Comment: Okay I will check it out. What do you mean mashing together strings? How else could I format this?

Comment: `$startTag . $content . $endTag` instead of DOM.

Comment: I've changed the code, I've got the information displaying, yet it's not in XML format. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean "it's not in XML format"? How do you expect the browser (are you looking at this in a browser?) to render it?

Comment: Yeah I'm viewing it in the browser, and I mean the output is literally the first names and last names listed without spaces, it doesn't include the <> tags such as <people> or <person>. Is this possible in a browser?

Comment: You could probably write an XSLT stylesheet to render the tags, or use CSS and `content` all over the place. I wouldn't bother though. XML isn't a good format for displaying directly to users. I'd express things in HTML if I wanted to render it for display in a browser.